# Running SFMC SSJS locally, not through SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm developing SSJS scripts, I'm debugging connectivity issues between SFMC and 3rd party remote service. I can connect to it from my computer locally, but SFMC is having difficulties connecting. I would like to try running SSJS locally on my own machine where I can guarantee it's connecting.

Is there a way to run SSJS locally, like through Node?

Comment: short answer is no. Long answer, you can validate all of your normal JS locally, but all SFMC SSJS functions are proprietary and will not work outside of the SFMC environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing from Comments to Answer for easier reference:

The short answer is no.

Long answer, you can validate all of your normal JS locally, but all SFMC SSJS functions are proprietary and will not work outside of the SFMC environment